# Python's shutil.make_archive() creates dot directory on Linux (when using tar or gztar)

Tags: python, shutil

I'm using a basic python script to create an archive with the contents of a directory "directoryX":

```
shutil.make_archive('NameOfArchive', format='gztar', root_dir=getcwd()+'/directoryX/')
```

The generated archive rather than just storing the contents of directoryX, creates a . folder in the archive (and the contents of folder directoryX are stored in this . folder).

Interestingly this only happens with .tar and tar.gz but not with .zip

Used python version -> 3.8.10

It seems that when using .tar or .tar.gz formats, the default base_dir of "./" gets accepted literally and it creates a folder titled "."
I tried using base_dir=os.currdir but got the same results...
Tried to also use python2 but got the same results.

Is this a bug with shutil.make_archive or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a documented behavior, sort of, just a little odd. The `base_dir` argument to `make_archive` is documented to:

1. Be the directory we start archiving from (after `chdir`ing to `root_dir`)
2. Default to the current directory (specifically, `os.curdir`)

`os.curdir` is actually a constant string, `'.'`, and, matching the `tar` command line utility, `shutil.make_archive` (and `tar.add` which it's implemented in terms of) stores the complete path "given" (in this case, `'./'` plus the rest of the relative path to the file). If you run `tar -c -z -C directoryX -f NameOfArchive.tar.gz .`, you'll end up with a tarball full of `./` prefixed files too (`-C directoryX` does the same thing as `root_dir`, and the `.` argument is the same as the default `base_dir='.'`).

I don't see an easy workaround that retains the simplicity of `shutil.make_archive`; if you try to pass `base_dir=''` it dies when it tries to `stat` `''`, so that's out.

To be clear, this behavior should be fine; a tar entry named `./foo` and one named `foo` are equivalent for most purposes. If it really bothers you, you can switch to using the `tarfile` module directly, e.g.:

```
# Imports at top of file
import os
import tarfile

# Actual code
with tarfile.open('NameOfArchive.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
    for entry in os.scandir('directoryX'):
        # Operates recursively on any directories, using the arcname as the base,
        # so you add the whole tree just by adding all the entries in the top
        # level directory. Using arcname of entry.name means it's equivalent to
        # adding os.path.basename(entry.path), omitting all directory components
        tar.add(entry.path, arcname=entry.name)

    # The whole loop *could* be replaced with just:
    # tar.add('directoryX', arcname='')
    # which would add all contents recursively, but it would also put an entry
    # for '/' in, which is undesirable
```

For a directory structure like:

```
directoryX/
  |
  \- foo
  \- bar
  \- subdir/
       |
       \- spam
       \- eggs
```

the resulting `tar`'s contents would be:

```
foo
bar
subdir/
subdir/eggs
subdir/spam
```

vs. the:

```
./foo
./bar
./subdir/
./subdir/eggs
./subdir/spam
```

your current code produces.

Slightly more work to code, but not *that* much worse; two imports and three lines of code, and with greater control over what gets added (for example, you could trivially exclude symlinks by wrapping the `tar.add` call in an `if not entry.is_symlink():` block, or omit recursive adding of specific directories by conditionally setting `recursive=False` to the `tar.add` call for directories you don't want to include the contents of; you can even provide a `filter` function to the `tar.add` call to conditionally exclude specific entries even when deep recursion gets involved).

Comment: Thank you for that, I will just use tarfile since I have another script that just looks for files inside the archive and doesn't expect another folder to be inside (and I do not want to edit this script since it is required for some other legacy scripts).
A question I have though, why does this only happen with .tar and .gztar?
If I used zip as the format this issue does not happen.

Comment: @iTsYaBoiii: It looks like the `shutil` utility function that implements `make_archive` for zip files uses `os.path.normpath`, which strips `./` prefixes. Even if it didn't, `zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file` (which is how a file from disk is added) uses `os.path.normpath` internally, so no matter how it does, a leading `./` is removed. I'm not sure off-hand if the zip format even allows relative path names beginning with `./`, so it may be doing this to avoid conflicting with the spec (where `tar` itself easily creates archives with such paths, and Python matches behavior).